# Indicator to see from which function a search string comes

Tags: string, function, search, vim, indicator

I have a number of functions that create search strings @/

I would like to know from which functions comes the search string.

Is it possible to add an indicator to the search string that doesn't influence the search string but what allows me to check from which function it comes?

p.e. `/[indicator]search string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a regexp *branch* that never matches, e.g. `/\%$indicator\|search string`

`\%$` is a special Vim atom matching the end of the file. Since that will never match when followed by the indicator text, the first branch (up to `\|`) will never match and therefore can represent your indicator.

Note that you cannot just use the `$` atom, since it matches the end-of-line only at certain places in the regexp, and a literal $ otherwise. (The same applies to other atoms like `^` and `[]`, so only some special Vim atoms (`\%c` is another one) can be used safely. Thanks to ib for pointing this out!)

Comment: Simple and effective.  Very nice.

Comment: This solution is not that universal.  The atom `$` matches end of line only at the end of a pattern or in front of `\|`, `\)`, or `\n`; otherwise, it matches literal dollar sign (see `:help /$`).  So, if there is a `$` followed by one of those indicators somewhere in the text, the proposed pattern *will* match.  Also, if an indicator starts with a newline character, the leading branch *will* match a newline followed by the remaining characters of indicator (if there is a line starting with them, of course).

Comment: That being said, I would recommend using one of the following patterns as branches that never match: `ind[]` (or `[]ind`), `ind\%0c`, `ind\%<1c`, `ind\%^`, or `\%$ind` (listed in decreasing order of personal preference).  These patterns are *guaranteed* to *not* match.

Comment: Unfortunately, the empty collection `ind[]` matches literally, too. I've adapted my answer to use `\%$`, because it acts like a sigil, alerting the user that `indicator` is not a regular search string. Thanks ib for pointing out that weakness!

Comment: Indeed, contrary to what appears from the documentation, `[]` does match literally.  Nevertheless, there is another solid alternative, `ind\<\>`.  Regarding "sigil" alerting, all of the atoms in patterns I propose except `\%^`, could be put in front of an indicator.  So `\<\>ind`, `\%0cind`, `\%<1cind` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I have turned this idea into a Vim plugin: [TaggedSearchPattern](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4123): Attach names to search patterns for easier recall.

This plugin allows you to "tag" individual searches with a name, so that these
searches are documented and therefore become easier to recognize and recall.
You can also pre-seed your search history with frequently needed searches.