# Is there a way to elegantly comment specific lines in vim search history, similar to " in command-line history?

Tags: search, vim, comments

I am using vim to edit structured text files.

Sometimes I use search-and-replace feature, and sometimes I am better off with search, followed with a macro, in which case I have several macros at hand, and the choice of one depends upon the particular search result.

In both cases, though I have to spend some effort to arrive at an acceptable regex to satisfy my editing needs. As the regexs are often very long and sophisticated, I end up with both command-line history and search history full of my trial-and-error by-products. The correct regex is not always the last one in a series of attempts, so if I want to reuse the hard-earned regex in a similar editing situation, I have to dig through the pile again.

In search-and-replace scenario I have quickly fixed this with comments that I now put in place at the end of a would-be reusable search-and-replace command string, for example:

`:%s/very_long_and_sophisticated_regex/another_long_and_sophisticated_regex/gc "comments on what this search and replace command does and how it might be reused`

This way I can easily ignore the piles of stuff in my command line history and quickly find relevant re-use candidates, they are shown in different color. The commands are reusable right away, comments are ignored.

Not so with the search history, though.

Having rtfmed and searched the web, I have not found anything similar. At the moment I put quasi-comments using XXX at the end of reusable search strings, for example:

`/search_string_containing_very_long_and_sophisticated_regex XXX comments on what it finds and how it might be re-used`

This way I can at least find the right string for re-use, but I have to first delete 'XXX' and the comments.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way of commenting the search strings in search history, similar to command-line history.

Comment: Another workaround might have been upgrading a search string to a search-and-replace command, had the upgrade worked the same way as a downgrade from search-and-replace to search, but it doesn,t: thus, if you quit a search-and-replace command and then press 'n' you will get the search portion of the command inserted into the search history, but if you type `:%s///gc` after a search, you will get the command working with your search string, but the search string does not travel to the command line history, it will contain only `:%s///gc`.

Comment: See also [Indicator to see from which function a search string comes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10174171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the word "elegant" in your title, and that I don't have on offer. If instead you can also accept a quirky workaround that relies on Vim internals, here's one.

To restate your problem, it is possible to add comments after Ex `:commands`,

```
:AComplicatedExCommand -42 -quux    " this fizzes the brobble
:HardToRememberCommand test.txt     " use this to brew the framble
```

but the same is not possible for complicated search `/queries` (or `?queries`).

I've just discovered that you can trick Vim by terminating your search query with a literal null byte:

```
/[Complicated]*regexp/^@              this regexp finds all scrobbles
/another\+Rege\x*p/^@                 use this to search foo bars
```

The `^@` here is a literal NUL. You can enter it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then `000`.

Vim will ignore everything after the null byte, but it'll still show the whole line in the search history, including the "comment".

Comment: This solution IS elegant by any conceivable standard! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Besides, ^@ is perfectly serchiable in the search history, which makes subsequent housekeeping a breeze: `/\v^(\zs.*\ze)&(.*^@)@!`, followed by `:%s///gc` lets you clean the history, leaving the commented lines intact.
`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a regexp *branch* that never matches, e.g. `/\%$indicator\|search string`

`\%$` is a special Vim atom matching the end of the file. Since that will never match when followed by the indicator text, the first branch (up to `\|`) will never match and therefore can represent your indicator.

I've created the [TaggedSearchPattern plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4123) to make adding the tag and recalling it even easier.

Comment: Naturally, you've already made a solution long ago :) I saw the honourable mention on the plugin page, thanks!

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Oh, that one really hurts -- I could have invented it myself! I will try using both yours and gits' solutions and will see which one is more convenient. I see your point of placing the comments ahead of the search string, which makes it possible to search them using auto-fill. On the other hand, I've long used to commenting commands in vim and in bash the traditional way, i.e. by appending the comments at the end of the line. We'll see. Thank you!